# I have to show the all values in lookup tables values as dropdown in UI I am using hibernate session query and I am storing in cache

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

But the cache is not storing values its querying each Tuple(line) of database which is even worse than implementing cache 
I have done this steps

1. Marking entity as `@Cachable`  and `@Cache(read only , my region)`
2. and session(set `Cachable = true`)
3. In hibernate configuration I have set use query `cache= true`
4. I am using `ehcache`

I want all the my POJO objects from the database table using cache someone please help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

this may be caused with many reasons, first of all, are you config query cache in your configuration XML file (witch is hibernate.cfg.xml in pure Hibernate project or persistence.xml in JPA Project)